# How can I get this VBA code to work with any selected columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm trying to get the min, max, average, and standard deviation for a set of numbers. I want to be able to select any columns and be able to find this data. Even if I had to conduct the selections seperatly. How can I get this to work? Look below:

```
Range("P4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(RC[-12]:RC[-8],RC[-6]:RC[-2])"
Range("Q4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-13]:RC[-9],RC[-7]:RC[-3])"
Range("R4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-14]:RC[-10],RC[-8]:RC[-4])"
Range("S4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV.S(RC[-15]:RC[-11],RC[-9]:RC[-5])"
Range("P4:S4").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P4:S68"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("P4:S68").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this:

```
With Selection
  .FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(RC[-12]:RC[-8],RC[-6]:RC[-2])"
  .Offset(,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-13]:RC[-9],RC[-7]:RC[-3])"
  .Offset(,2).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-14]:RC[-10],RC[-8]:RC[-4])"
  .Offset(,3).FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV.S(RC[-15]:RC[-11],RC[-9]:RC[-5])"
End With
```